# `ggsave` prints a graph which is different from the original one

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am using `ggplot` with `R` using the GUI `RStudio`.
I am facing a strange issue, it looks like a graph made with `ggplot` plotted on the graphical part of `RStudio` gets printed on a different way when saved with `ggsave`.

Here I report the example code:

```
##Generation of the dataframe
Textile <- data.frame(
  Product = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Vix = c(32000, 20000, 30000, 17000, 30000),
  OT = c(2.5, 7, 17.5, 11, 5),
  Otbis = c("2-3", "6-8", "13-15", "10-12", "4-6"),
  Vixbis = c("27-37000", "15-25000", "25-35000", "14-20000", "20-30000")
)

View(Textile)
Textile


##Libraries loading
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)



##Variales creation
Product<-Textile[[1]]
Vix<-Textile[[2]]
OT<-Textile[[3]]

###Redefinition name first Row
row.names(Textile) <- Product


### Theme defined
theme_set(
  theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
  )




##Graph creation, I named it nbaplot
nbaplot <- ggplot(Textile, aes(x= OT, y = Vix, label = Product)) +   
geom_point(color = "red", size = 2) +  
xlab("X-axis") + 
ylab("Y-axis") +
geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = Inf, segment.curvature = 0.1, segment.ncp = 3, segment.angle = 60, force = 10,   size = 2.5, angle = 0, segment.alpha = 0.25, segment.size = 0.15,  nudge_y = 0.5, segment.square =FALSE, min.segment.length = 1, family = "Calibri", box.padding = 2.5, point.padding = 2.5, aes(label=paste0(Product, "\n", "Viscosity: ", Vixbis, " mPa s", "\n", "Defined time: ", Otbis, " sec")),
    size = 3,
     hjust=1
  )

nbaplot
```

Which generates me this graph, on the `RStudio` windows, which is nice.

[image]

Then I try to export using the `ggsave` function and the positioning of the labels is different from the one created making the graph earlier on with `nbaplot`.

```
ggsave(filename="Grafico.png", plot=nbaplot, device="png", dpi=500) #Ti salva il grafico nella Working directory del progetto
ggsave(filename="GraficoWide.png", plot=nbaplot, device="png", dpi=500, width = 5197, height = 2864, units = "px") #Formato Wide
```

[image]
[image]

How can I export the really generated `nbaplot` graph?

Comment: From the documentation for ggrepel: "The text labels are repositioned after resizing a plot."  So as you create plots with different sizes, the text labels could move around.  You can save the plot image directly with the RStudio GUI, I don't know if there's code for this.

Comment: You can save it with `RStudio GUI` but it saves the images with a very poor resolution. Just click on "Save image as ..."